# QTableView: selected cell messes up painting

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, selection, paint, qtableview

I want to customize the look of my QTableView. Therefore, I decided to disable the gridlines and do the painting myself. I subclassed QStyledItemDelegate and re-implemented its paint method. It all works fine, until I select some cells in my table. The selection somehow messes up the painting...

At the end, I provided a little demo application.

If you run the application, just click on a cell named "Night" and you will see what I mean. How can I change that?

I thought about invoking a re-paint, after the user selects a cell, but that didn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks a lot!

**main.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

import sys

from productiontable import productionTableModel
from productiontable import productionTableBorder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tableview = QtGui.QTableView()
    model = productionTableModel([["Prod. 1"], ["Prod. 2"], ["Prod. 3"], ["Prod. 4"], ["Prod. 5"]])

    tableview.setModel(model)

    tableview.resizeColumnsToContents()
    tableview.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tableview.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tableview.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
    tableview.setShowGrid(False)
    tableview.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus) #remove dotted line, when cell has focus
    tableview.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    d = productionTableBorder()
    tableview.setItemDelegate(d)

    tableview.resize(100, 300)
    tableview.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**productiontable.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class productionTableBorder(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        if index.row()%2 == 0:
            painter.save() 
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 4))

            #draw a white line from start to end
            start = QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y())
            end = QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x() + option.rect.width(), option.rect.y())
            painter.drawLine(start, end)

            painter.restore()

class productionTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, lst = [[]], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__lst = lst

    def rowCount(self, parent = None):
        return len(self.__lst) * 2

    def columnCount(self,  parent = None):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        col = index.column()
        row = index.row()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if col == 0:
                if row%2 == 0:
                    return self.__lst[row/2][col]
            if col == 1:
                if row%2 == 0:
                    return "Day"
                else:
                    return "Night"

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QColor(188, 250, 213)

    def flags(self, index):
        return (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it.

To paint your own gridlines, you need to **subclass QTableView**, subclassing QStyledItemDelegate doesn't work! If you subclass QStyledItemDelegate and override its paint() method you also need to re-calculate the size of the cell (because of the gridlines).

It is way better to subclass QTableView and do the painting of the gridlines in the paintEvent.

Here is my solution (inspired by [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52742-Draw-Grid-lines-with-Painter) thread):

**main.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

import sys

from productiontable import productionTableModel
from productiontable import customTable

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tableview = customTable()
    model = productionTableModel([["Prod. 1"], ["Prod. 2"], ["Prod. 3"], ["Prod. 4"], ["Prod. 5"]])

    tableview.setModel(model)

    tableview.resizeColumnsToContents()
    tableview.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tableview.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
    tableview.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
    tableview.setShowGrid(False)
    tableview.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus) #remove dotted line, when cell has focus
    tableview.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    tableview.resize(100, 300)
    tableview.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**productiontable.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class customTable(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(customTable, self).paintEvent(event)

        #set the pen
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 4)

        # Create the painter
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())

        # Shortcuts to vertical and horizontal headers
        vh = self.verticalHeader()
        hh = self.horizontalHeader()

        # Get the first and last rows that are visible in the view and if the 
        # last visiable row returns -1 set it to the row count
        firstVisualRow = max([vh.visualIndexAt(0), 0])
        lastVisualRow = vh.visualIndexAt(vh.viewport().height())
        if lastVisualRow == -1:
            lastVisualRow = self.model().rowCount(self.rootIndex()) - 1

        # Get the first and last columns that are visible in the view and if 
        # if the last visible column is -1 set it to the column count.
        firstVisualColumn = max([hh.visualIndexAt(0), 0])
        lastVisualColumn = hh.visualIndexAt(hh.viewport().width())
        if lastVisualColumn == -1:
            lastVisualColumn = hh.count() - 1

        # Iterate through each row and column drawing only the
        # bottom and left side lines for each cell. Skipping rows and columns
        # that are hidden
        for vrow in xrange(firstVisualRow, lastVisualRow + 1, 2):
            row = vh.logicalIndex(vrow)
            FirstRow = (vrow == 0)
            if vh.isSectionHidden(row):
                continue
            # Get top left Y coordinate and row height
            rowY = self.rowViewportPosition(row)
            rowh = self.rowHeight(row)
            for vcol in range(firstVisualColumn, lastVisualColumn + 1):
                col = hh.logicalIndex(vcol)
                FirstColumn = (vcol == 0)
                if hh.isSectionHidden(col):
                    continue
                # Get top left X coordinate and column width
                colX = self.columnViewportPosition(col)
                colw = self.columnWidth(col)

                # Get the model index 
                index = self.model().createIndex(row, col)

                # Specify top, bottom, left and right of the cell
                top = rowY
                bottom = rowY
                left = colX
                right = colX + colw

                # Save the painter and set the pen
                painter.save()
                painter.setPen(pen)

                # Draw Horizontal Lines
                painter.drawLine(left, bottom, right, bottom)

                # Restore painter
                painter.restore()


class productionTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, lst = [[]], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__lst = lst

    def rowCount(self, parent = None):
        return len(self.__lst) * 2

    def columnCount(self,  parent = None):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        col = index.column()
        row = index.row()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if col == 0:
                if row%2 == 0:
                    return self.__lst[row/2][col]
            if col == 1:
                if row%2 == 0:
                    return "Day"
                else:
                    return "Night"

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QColor(188, 250, 213)

    def flags(self, index):
        return (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```